# NetworkExtension - entitlements

Tags: ios, swift, entitlements

I have a PacketTunnelProvider app extension, with a plist containing the keys

```
    NSExtensionPointIdentifier
    NSExtensionPrincipalClass
```

I got the entitlements from Apple to use the Networking extension

on the containing app, Im trying to call

```
self.vpnManager?.saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler({ (error) -> Void in
                        if (error != nil) {
```

but I get the error -

```
Error Domain=NEVPNErrorDomain Code=5 "permission denied" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=permission denied
```

(also, I don't see any entitlements on the containing app, and I have a suspicious that I need them there too)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: O.K, I created a new provision profile with the network entitlement and now it's working, but still, I don't have an entitlements file which should be there (am I wrong?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, It was something with the provisioning profile.
The entitlements, by the way, should be both on the containing app and on the extension app

Comment: (Im not deleting this question for the tiny chance that it will help someone someday)